# How to open Youtube url in UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I have an array with Youtube URL and I want to displayed it in a WebView I know how to display an URL :

```
videoHTML = @"<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"305\" height=\"180\" src=\"http://www.cast-tv.biz/play/?clid=23595&amp;media=yes&amp;movId=cgjlej\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
```

but how can I replace the address with another URL from my array?

Comment: Hint : [nsstring stringwithformat] ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html )

Answer (score 0):

It's simple all you need to do is use the `stringWithFormat:` instance method like

```
// Our array of URLs
NSArray *urlArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"http://www.cast-tv.biz/play/?clid=23595&amp;media=yes&amp;movId=cgjlej", 
                     @"http://www.google.com",
                     @"http://news.yahoo.com"];

// Construct the with the object at index '0' 
NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"305\" height=\"180\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", [urlArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Checkout the Apple Documentation for [`NSString stringWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:) for more information on this instance method